# tlsharp mark as read channel post

Tags: c#, telegram

```
var Channellist = (await client.SendRequestAsync<TeleSharp.TL.Contacts.TLResolvedPeer>(
               new TeleSharp.TL.Contacts.TLRequestResolveUsername
               {
                   Username = "nedocoder"
               }).ConfigureAwait(true)).Chats;

            if (Channellist.Count > 0)
            {
                var ChannelInfo = Channellist[0] as TeleSharp.TL.TLChannel;
                var peer = new TLInputPeerUser() { UserId = ChannelInfo.Id, AccessHash = (long)ChannelInfo.AccessHash };
                var ch = new TLInputChannel() { ChannelId = ChannelInfo.Id, AccessHash = (long)ChannelInfo.AccessHash };
                var abs = new TLInputPeerChannel() { ChannelId = ChannelInfo.Id, AccessHash = (long)ChannelInfo.AccessHash };

                var req = new TLRequestGetHistory
                {
                    AddOffset = 0,
                    Limit = 1,
                    Peer = abs
                };
                TLChannelMessages res = await client.SendRequestAsync<TLChannelMessages>(req);

                foreach (TeleSharp.TL.TLMessage msg in res.Messages)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        int mID = msg.Id;
                        string TMessage = msg.Message;
                        string TvisitCount = msg.Views.ToString();

                        MessageBox.Show(mID + ' ' + TMessage + ' ' + TvisitCount + ' ');
                        var markAsRead = new TeleSharp.TL.Channels.TLRequestReadHistory()
                        {


                            Channel = ch,

                           // MaxId = -1,
                            MessageId = mID,
                            // Dirty = true,
                            //  MessageId = 356217,
                            // ConfirmReceived = true,
                            //Sequence = dia.unread_count

                        };
                        var affectedMessages = await client.SendRequestAsync<bool>(markAsRead);
                        MessageBox.Show(mID + ' ' + TMessage + ' '+ TvisitCount + ' ' +affectedMessages);


                    }
                    catch { }
                }
```

Пытаюсь прочитать сообщение канала, успещно получаю id сообщения, его текст и кол-во просмотров. markAsRead возвращает true, что гвоорит нам о том, что сообщение просмотренно, но счетчик просмотров не обновляется, может я где-то ошибся? Я не могу понять где, буду благодарен за любую помощь!

UPD: скорее всего правильный метод для просмотров этот :

```
                   TLVector<int> idd = new TLVector<int>();
                    var msgviews = new TLRequestGetMessagesViews()
                    {
                        Peer = abs,
                        MessageId = mID,
                        Increment = true,
                        Id = idd

                    };
                    var resultl = await client.SendRequestAsync<TLVector<int>>(msgviews);
                    MessageBox.Show(" "+resultl);
```

Но получаю такой ответ и ничего не происходит
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а почему вы решили что счётчик должен инкрементироваться при программном «просмотре»?

Comment: Ну а как? У меня же должна быть возможность засчитать просморт через телеграм апи?